# Getting an issue with my User Interface in React Native Extra space added not removing

Tags: react-native

[image: Here i am getting issue]I am trying to build a User Interface but i am getting an issue in my Layout extra space is added at the space of Header and header moving down i am not understanding how to resolve this issue i am attaching an Image of the layout please help.

Here is my code...

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import {createStackNavigator, createAppContainer , createBottomTabNavigator} from 'react-navigation'; 
import { DrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import AntIcon from "react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign";
import home from './src/Home/home';
import EmployerLayout from './src/Home/EmployerLayout';
import Employers from './src/CompleteEmployers/Employers';
import Jobs from './src/CompleteJobs/Jobs';
import Freelancers from './src/CompleteFreelancers/Freelancers';
import Profile from './src/ProfileSetting/Profile'; 
import DetailFreelancerScreen from './src/DetailFreelancer/DetailFreelancerScreen';
import DetailJobScreen from './src/DetailJobs/DetailJobScreen';
import DetailCompanyScreen from './src/DetailCompany/DetailCompanyScreen';
import SearchScreen from './src/DetailSearch/SearchScreen';
console.disableYellowBox = true;
const BaseUrl= "https://amentotech.com/projects/api_workreap/wp-json/api/v1";

const MainNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  // MainNavigator: MainDrawer},{
  Home:{
    screen: home,
    navigationOptions:{
      tabBarLabel:'Home',  
      tabBarIcon:({tintColor})=>(
        <AntIcon name="home" color={tintColor} size={25} />
      )
    }
  },
  Jobs:{
    screen: Jobs,
    navigationOptions:{
      tabBarLabel:'Jobs',  
      tabBarIcon:({tintColor})=>(
        <AntIcon name="appstore-o" color={tintColor} size={25} />
      )
    }
  },
  Freelancers:{
    screen: Freelancers,
    navigationOptions:{
      tabBarLabel:'Freelancers',  
      tabBarIcon:({tintColor})=>(
        <AntIcon name="user" color={tintColor} size={25}/>
      )
    }
  },
  Employers:{
    screen: Employers,
    navigationOptions:{
      tabBarLabel:'Employers',  
      tabBarIcon:({tintColor})=>(
        <AntIcon name="wallet" color={tintColor} size={25}/>
      )

    }
  },
  Profile:{
    screen: Profile,
    navigationOptions:{
      tabBarLabel:'Profile',  
      tabBarIcon:({tintColor})=>(
        <AntIcon name="setting" color={tintColor} size={25} />
      )

    }
  }
},
{
  defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
    tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
      const { routeName } = navigation.state;
      let IconComponent = CONST.IC_HOME;
      if (routeName === CONST.MENU_HOME) {
        IconComponent = focused ? CONST.IC_HOME_SELECTED : CONST.IC_HOME;
      } else if (routeName === CONST.MENU_CALENDAR) {
        IconComponent = focused ? CONST.IC_CALENDAR_SELECTED : CONST.IC_CALENDAR;
      } 
      return IconComponent;
    }
  }),
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: '#ff5851',

  },


});
const RootStack= createStackNavigator({
  home:MainNavigator,
  Profile:Profile,
  Employers:Employers,
  Jobs:Jobs,
  DetailFreelancerScreen:DetailFreelancerScreen,
  DetailJobScreen:DetailJobScreen,
  DetailCompanyScreen:DetailCompanyScreen,
  SearchScreen:SearchScreen,
  EmployerLayout:EmployerLayout,
})


const App = createAppContainer(RootStack);

export default App;
```

Here is my code of `App.js` i am getting this issue from here please help

Comment: Add screenshots and Code it will help us identify the issue.

Comment: Please Check @AshwinMothilal i have added Screen Shot

Comment: Please share your navigation code.

Answer (score 1):

What you currently have is the `react-navigation`'s header and your own header.

To fix your issue in a specific component / screen, add the following:

```
static navigationOptions = {
  header: null
};
```

Comment: @S.Hashmi did you add it under `class Home extends Component` ?

Answer (score 1):

Set **header mode** to **none** while creating Stack Navigator. Please refer issue link [here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/2150#issuecomment-392613359) along with [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html)

```
headerMode: 'none',
navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
  header: null,
}),

const RootStack= createStackNavigator({
  home:MainNavigator,
  Profile:Profile,
  Employers:Employers,
  Jobs:Jobs,
  DetailFreelancerScreen:DetailFreelancerScreen,
  DetailJobScreen:DetailJobScreen,
  DetailCompanyScreen:DetailCompanyScreen,
  SearchScreen:SearchScreen,
  EmployerLayout:EmployerLayout,
  headerMode: 'none',
  navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
  header: null,
  }),
})
```

Comment: Not picking navigationOptions showing error ... the component for route 'navigationOptions' must be a react component

Comment: @S.Hashmi please try now

Comment: I hope you have installed fresh build for testing. As per documentation, it should work

Comment: Ok let me try it

Comment: Its not working i have start expo again still it is as the same display :(

Comment: You can try asking [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26424/iosandroidchaosoverflow) if someone can help you out. Good luck dude!